# How do we group data in JAVA like we use struct in C

Tags: java, android

In JAVA, do we have any other way similar to "struct in C" other than class.

I'm trying to convert one of my project written in C to JAVA.
The problem I'm facing is, if I have multiple structures in C that is mainly used to group the data, I want to avoid writing those many classes in multiple files.

Thanks

Comment: "I want to avoid writing those many classes in multiple files." - You can write many classes in the same file provided only one of them is public.

Comment: (Or they can all be public; as long as there is only one public non-inner class. Using inner [static] classes may be appropriate if just desiring a logical grouping of "structs".)

Comment: @user2864740 - agreed.. I left out the finer details considering the fact that ajit has worked/working on "C".

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested classes for close related structs to avoid using many files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Enum in your project. I think it may solve your problem.